# Express and Typescript - Error.stack and Error.status properties do not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

I'm trying to convert an existing node.js project from javascript to typescript. I've been using the default 404 error catcher from the Visual Studio Express 4 template:

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:
*Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Error'.*

I get a similar message if I try and invoke the Error's .stack property:
*Property 'stack' does not exist on type 'Error'.*

Does anyone know what's going on here?

**Edit:** Steve Fenton points out that I could just put the error status on the response object. However, my error handling mechanism uses a two-step process:

1. Create the 404 error and set its status
2. Hand it on to the following generic handler:

   ```
   app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
       res.status(err.status || 500);
       res.render('error', {
           message: err.message,
           error: {}
       });
   });
   ```

So the error status is first set on the Error object, then read back by the error handler to decide how to handle the error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Extend global `Error`

You can tell TypeScript that for *your* use case `Error` might have a `status` on it:

```
interface Error {
    status?: number;
}
```

So you get:

```
interface Error {
    status?: number;
}

var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
```

## Alternative

Put the status on the `res` and send the `err`. For Example:

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    res.status(404); // using response here
    next(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Basarat. I just assumed this was an appropriate way to do things because it's how it's done in the Visual Studio Express 4 template.

Comment: Ouch. *bad visual studio team*

Comment: This template, was it js template or typescript template?

Comment: The OP's code looks idiomatic with regard to _Express_ (per [https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html], i.e. `res.statusCode` is set from `err.status` (or `err.statusCode`). (Also `headers`) - but shouldn't the Express types then contain something like:
`declare global {
  // Shouldn't Express do this?
  interface Error {
    status?: number;
    statusCode?: number;
    headers: [string]
  }
}` ? (Sorry for the poor formatting) - is there discussion on this somewhere already?

Comment: And how do you tell typescript that `Error` has `status` on it?

Comment: Typescript interfaces with the same name extends existing interfaces; hence, Typescript will extend the existing Error interface with the new Error interface with status property.

Comment: @TimothyJohns, i can't seem to find in the documentation that `res.statusCode` is set from `err.status` and vice versa. If you don't mind can you share a link to that part.

Comment: I prefer adding `extends Error` like RaidenF proposed

Answer (score 28):

The best way in my opinion, is not to disable type checks by setting the error to `any`, or creating a new `Error` type, since one already exists in `@types/node`.

Instead, you should extend that error type:

```
interface ResponseError extends Error {
  status?: number;
}
```

Comment: I'll recommend the above approach, which looks more sophisticated to me

Comment: Is there any way that I can make this globally?

Comment: I think that the accepted answer does what you need

Answer (score 12):

```
import * as express from 'express';
interface Error {
  status?: number;
  message?: string;
}

app.use((err: Error, req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: err
  });
});
```

Comment: It makes a nicer answer if you use some words to help the OP understand what part of your code resolves their question.

Answer (score 8):

You put the error code on the response...

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    res.status(404)
    next(err);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

This is generally a question of how to lazily initialize objects in Typescript.

The ideal way to do this is:

```
interface ErrorWithStatus extends Error {
    status: string
}

let foo = new Error() as ErrorWithStatus;
foo.status = '404';
```

Using `any`, or interfaces with nullable fields, leave you with subpar and weak contracts.

Comment: It should be `as ErrorWithStatus`. But you get my upvote :-)

Answer (score 8):

If I am not mistaken it is always best to get the type that is actually expected. I couldn't find any hard support that I am right, but I use:

```
import createError, { HttpError } from 'http-errors';
```

and to be complete for all types I also import the parameter types of use:

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
```

The actual function I use then looks like this:

```
app.use((err: HttpError, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => { ... }
```

In your case if you want to create your own error:

```
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  next(createError(404));
});
```

or closer to your code:

```
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  let err = new HttpError('Not found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option in TypeScript:

```
let err: any;
err = new Error();
err.status = 404;
```

Comment: Making the type `any` completely gives up one of the greatest advantages of Typescript - type-checking and enforcement.  This solution probably goes against the OP's objective for switching from JavaScript to Typescript in the first place. Some of the others are better in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

I just went for

```
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err['status'] = 404;
```

Comment: OP is using TypeScript.  This solution will give up the ability to use intellisense/autocomplete b/c the compiler won't understand the full shape of Error, so some of the others are better in my opinion.